# Has my self-invoking workaround worked or is it coincidence?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been having an issue with a Google Apps Script I'm running that kept throwing the following error when ever I triggered the code onChange. No such errors were returned when I manually ran the code.

Exception: Service Documents failed while accessing document with id XXXX

The error was happening on the same line of code each time and I've subsequently found that this is a relatively common error and is perhaps happening because my script is quite lengthy and perhaps not as efficient as it should be (I'm very much an Apps Script and JS novice). Interestingly I have a very similar script (with perhaps 20% less variables) running in another file that executes as expected every time.

I had no naming or scoping issues with the variable that was being used to call the document but I thought that perhaps wrapping the troublesome part of the script into a self-invoking function within the larger function would minimise hoisting and improve the efficiency of the script - at least enough to let it run consistently without errors. My understanding of JS is that when a script initiates variable declarations are hoisted within their scope and therefore by creating a self-invoking function I could reduce the hoisting within the main function which contains in excess of 100 variables and therefore reduce the initial demand.

So far the script does appear to be running more quickly and avoiding the error that I'd previously being seeing - the last run was just over 63 seconds whereas the previous successful manual run without the self-invoking function was just under 103 seconds.

I do believe this can be an intermittent error and I'm trying to find a robust, longer term fix without having to rewrite all of my code.

I have detailed the self-invoking code below with any IDs redacted. The part that was causing the error within the script was "var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);

Do you think this could be a genuine fix or has the code started to work coincidently because of the intermittent nature of this error?

```
    var docTempId = "XXXX";//Template File Id
    var docFinalId = "XXXX"; //Final File Id
    var sheetId = "XXXX";

 (function () { // self-invoked within larger function to minimise hoisting
    var docTemp = DocumentApp.openById(docTempId);
    var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
     docFinal.getBody().clear();
    var templateParagraphs = docTemp.getBody().getParagraphs();
    
     createMailMerge(Company,Branch,PropertyID,PropertyAddress,ApplicantName,Dateofbirth1,EmailAddress,PhoneNumber,Nationality,PassportNumber,NationalInsuranceNumber,Currentresidentialstatus,LeaseRequested,RentOfferedPCM,TotalNumberofAdultOccupants,Proposedleasecommencementdate1,TotalRentPayers,RentPayer2Name,RentPayer2Phone,RentPayer2Email,RentPayer3Name,RentPayer3Phone,RentPayer3Email,Relationshipwithadultoccupants,Numberofchildren,Ageofchildchildren,Currenteconomicstatus,Applicantoccupation,Applicantemployedorselfemployed,ApplicantDeclaredIncome,SelfEmployedDocuments,EmploymentPartorFullTime,EmploymentContractorPermanent,MainEmploymentCompany,Mainemploymentaddress,Mainemploymentstartdate1,Mainemploymemtpensionpayrollnumber,MainEmploymentManager,ManagerEmail,ManagerPhoneNumber,ApplicantPaymentType,ApplicantHourlyRate,Applicantprimaryaveragehourspermonth,Applicantsalary,ReceivesHousingBenefit,HousingBenefitAmount,Anyadditionalincome,Typeofadditonalincome,Secondemploymentcompany,Rolewithin2ndCompany,ndEmployeraddress,ndEmploymentstartdate1,ndEmployerpensionpayrollnumber,ndEmploymentContact,ndEmploymentEmail,ndEmploymentphonenumber,Additionalincomeamount,Additionalincomedetails,TotalDeclaredGrossIncome,Applicansavingsdeclared,MostRecentAddress,DateStartedlivingincurrentaddress1,Liveanywhereelseinlast3years,Applicant2ndresidingaddress,Applicant2ndaddressmoveindate1,Applicant2ndaddressmoveoutdate1,Applicantadditionaladdressdeclared,Applicantadditionaladdressdetails,Applicantadditonaladdressmoveindate1,Applicantadditionaladdressmoveoutdate1,Applicantpreviouslandlordreference,Landlordreferenceaddress,referencefromlandlordoragent,LandlordAgentName,lengthoftimeatproperty,LandlordAgentphonenumber,LandlordAgentemailaddress,Previouslandlordreferencepreventionreason,Anypets,Petdetails,Applicantsmoke,Applicantsmokeinside,Applicantadversecredit,Adversecreditdetails,Applicantprovidecurrentaccount,Applicantcurrentaccountname,Applicantcurrentaccountbank,Applicantcurrentaccountnumber,Applicantcurrentaccountsortcode,UKbasedguarantor,GuarantorName,GuarantorEmail,GuarantorPhoneNo,Noguarantorreason,NextofKinName,NextofKinrelationship,NextofKinEmail,NoNextofKinPhoneNo,Applicantadditionalinfo,Applicantdocuments,Applicantaccurateinformationdeclaration,Applicantaccepttermsandconditions,submittedatt,Token,maidenname,ApplicantReferencingChoice,Applicantcanprovide,Applicantdocumentlink,ApplicantacceptsHomelet,ApplicantallowsHomelettocontactreferences,ApplicanthappyforHomelet,templateParagraphs,docFinal);
    docFinal.saveAndClose();
    createPDF(); // calls the next function
    }) ();
```

Comment: *the main function which contains in excess of 100 variables* it sounds quite horrible. For a script. For a JS novice. Probably it makes sense to consider to use objects?

Comment: I'm assuming this would this improve the efficiency of the script Yuri? As a side note, I have managed to get the script to work by duplicating the document that was being pulled as the final file and using the new document ID. Whether this is because this is a new document and it's been called less times or there was an underlying issue with the original document, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Objects hardly will improve efficiency of the script. But they can vastly improve readability of code. Frankly I don't know how you can improve efficiency of runtime. It's need to dive deep into your code. And, yeah, it's not unlikely that the intermittent error has to do with complexity of your script.

Comment: Does this happen only with this specific document id? Also, is this the error you were getting before the workaround as well? @NickyMoorhead

Comment: Hi @ale13, yes the same error was occurring pre and post the introduction of the self-invoking function. I have duplicated the document that was causing the error and I'm now calling the the duplicated version of the document which so far negated the issue. I'm not sure if I'll start to see the error occurring again once the document is called more frequently but I guess time will tell.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @Yuri, I find the code very readable. Each variable related to a column within the sheet then relates to a value within the sheet and the variables are methodically defined in order using their co-ordinates from column A to column DH (final column).

Comment: Your [mcve] is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

The script has just failed again. After working on a number of occasions which hadn't been happening, it has now failed and return the same error as before. I can therefore only assume that creating a self-invoking function within the main function has made no material difference to the efficiency of the script.

Answer (score 0):

**The error you are receiving does not seem to be the expected one.**

I think the best solution in this situation is to file a bug on Google's Issue Tracker by using the template [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=823905).